# Is there a function that sums dependent data types?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas with the columns `Year` (int), `Loc` (ordered pair of ints), and `Rain` (boolean). There are many data points of `Rain` for each `Year`. For example, in the graph, you might see:

```
Year     |    Loc     |     Rain
1700          (0, 0)          1
1700          (0, 0)          1
1700          (5, 6)          0
```

etc.

Is there a function that will combine these data points into a single data point if `Year` AND `Loc` are the same, with `Rain` as the sum of all the `Rain` points of the corresponding `Year` AND `Loc` points?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to group by "Year" and "Loc" and show SUM of Rain? something like the following?

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Loc']).sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

there. This should do the trick as well:

```
# Just a dict of your data
dd = {'year':(1700,1700,1700),'loc':((0,0),(0,0),(5,6)),'rain':(1,1,0)}

df = DataFrame(dd)
# Set an index, groupby and count aggregate. 
adjusted_df = df.set_index(['year','loc']).groupby(level=['year','loc']).count()
```

Though this is almost exactly the same as the first solution. First solution is probably better (less code).